# Using YouTube Data Api in Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, gdata-api

Am trying to use YouTube Data Api in my android app. When i try to run it as a java project, it runs fine without any errors. But when i try to do the same thing in my android application , the application force closes. Here is the output from logcat and my code.

OUTPUT FROM LOGCAT

```
01-05 00:13:17.198: E/AndroidRuntime(627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 00:13:17.198: E/AndroidRuntime(627): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-05 00:13:17.198: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.example.allinonedata.YouTubeManager.retrieveVideos(YouTubeManager.java:29)
...
01-05 00:13:17.198: E/AndroidRuntime(627): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaSource
```

HERE IS THE CODE
mainactivity.java

```
  package com.example.allinonedata;
 import java.util.List;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.view.Menu;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String clientID = "JavaCodeGeeks";
String textQuery = "nexus 4";
int maxResults = 1;
boolean filter = true;
int timeout = 2000;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    YouTubeManager ym = new YouTubeManager(clientID);
    try{
    List<YouTubeVideo> videos = ym.retrieveVideos(textQuery, maxResults, filter, timeout);

    for (YouTubeVideo youtubeVideo : videos) {
        System.out.println(youtubeVideo.getWebPlayerUrl());

        System.out.println("Thumbnails");
        for (String thumbnail : youtubeVideo.getThumbnails()) {
            System.out.println("\t" + thumbnail);
        }
        System.out.println(youtubeVideo.getEmbeddedWebPlayerUrl());
        System.out.println("**************************************************");
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

youtubemanager.java

```
 package com.example.allinonedata;

 import java.net.URL;
 import java.util.LinkedList;
 import java.util.List;

 import com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeQuery;
 import com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeService;
 import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.MediaThumbnail;
 import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.VideoEntry;
 import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.VideoFeed;
 import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YouTubeMediaContent;
 import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YouTubeMediaGroup;

 public class YouTubeManager {

private static final String YOUTUBE_URL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos";
private static final String YOUTUBE_EMBEDDED_URL = "http://www.youtube.com/v/";

private String clientID;

public YouTubeManager(String clientID) {
    this.clientID = clientID;
}

public List<YouTubeVideo> retrieveVideos(String textQuery, int maxResults, 
        boolean filter, int timeout) throws Exception {

    YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(clientID);
    service.setConnectTimeout(timeout); // millis
    YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(new URL(YOUTUBE_URL));

    query.setOrderBy(YouTubeQuery.OrderBy.RELEVANCE);
    query.setFullTextQuery(textQuery);
    query.setSafeSearch(YouTubeQuery.SafeSearch.NONE);
    query.setMaxResults(maxResults);

    VideoFeed videoFeed = service.query(query, VideoFeed.class);        
    List<VideoEntry> videos = videoFeed.getEntries();

    return convertVideos(videos);

}

private List<YouTubeVideo> convertVideos(List<VideoEntry> videos) {

    List<YouTubeVideo> youtubeVideosList = new LinkedList<YouTubeVideo>();

    for (VideoEntry videoEntry : videos) {

        YouTubeVideo ytv = new YouTubeVideo();

        YouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup = videoEntry.getMediaGroup();
        String webPlayerUrl = mediaGroup.getPlayer().getUrl();
        ytv.setWebPlayerUrl(webPlayerUrl);

        String query = "?v=";
        int index = webPlayerUrl.indexOf(query);
        String embeddedWebPlayerUrl = webPlayerUrl.substring(index+query.length());
        embeddedWebPlayerUrl = YOUTUBE_EMBEDDED_URL + embeddedWebPlayerUrl;
        ytv.setEmbeddedWebPlayerUrl(embeddedWebPlayerUrl);

        List<String> thumbnails = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (MediaThumbnail mediaThumbnail : mediaGroup.getThumbnails()) {
            thumbnails.add(mediaThumbnail.getUrl());
        }           
        ytv.setThumbnails(thumbnails);

        List<YouTubeMedia> medias = new LinkedList<YouTubeMedia>();
        for (YouTubeMediaContent mediaContent : mediaGroup.getYouTubeContents()) {
            medias.add(new YouTubeMedia(mediaContent.getUrl(), mediaContent.getType()));
        }
        ytv.setMedias(medias);

        youtubeVideosList.add(ytv);

    }

    return youtubeVideosList;

}
```

}

Comment: see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/GkJWSkIYwXs) discussion about same issue

Comment: The YouTube/GData Java client library isn't compatible with Android. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube-api-gdata/GkJWSkIYwXs/i7wflv7l_KwJ

Comment: @MatiasMolinas okay...is there any other api that i can use? can i use json or jsonc?

Answer (score 2):

The google-api-java-client (which does have Android support, unlike the gdata-client) didn't previously support the Youtube Data API, but with the release of v3 this is now rectified; there is good Youtube support now with this client that should provide you what you need. See here for details and code samples:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3

and also to Getting started Guide here

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started